# Doubts about working with API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, xml, soap, soap-api-v1

I have to make a method to send my login and password to a website and get the xml it returns, its gonna be a list of products. What would be the best way? My options are: **SOAP 1.1**, **SOAP 1.2**, **GET** and **POST**? 
Also, how could I read the xml it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did with Get method, here is the code

```
    $url = 'http://urlexample';

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    );

    $method = 'GET';

    $connection = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();

    if ($method == "GET") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::GET;
    } elseif ($method == "POST") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::POST;
    } elseif ($method == "PUT") {
        $zendMethod = Zend_Http_Client::PUT;

        //ADICIONA AS OPTIONS MANUALMENTE POIS NATIVAMENTE O WRITE NAO VERIFICA POR PUT
        $connection->addOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        $connection->addOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    }

    $connection->setConfig(
        array(
        'timeout'   => 30
        )
    );

    $connection->write($zendMethod, $url, '1.0', $headers, $body);
    $response = $connection->read();
    $connection->close();

    $httpCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($response);
    $response = Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($response);


    echo "<textarea>" . $response . "</textarea>" ;
```